# How to run 32bit native library on 64bit JVM application

Tags: tomcat, x86, java-native-interface, jna

I have a 32bit-only native library linked to java application inside a tomcat container.
I would like to run tomcat with a x64 jre, is it possible? May I need a x64 wrapper for the native lib?

Comment: related: [Combine 32- and 64bit drivers in one program](//stackoverflow.com/q/55124756) has some suggestions for Windows workarounds like a COM server, which might be a stopgap if you really can't replace an obsolete 32-bit binary-only DLL.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a 32bit-only native library linked to java application inside a tomcat container. I would like to run tomcat with a x64 jre, is it possible?

That is not possible.  A 32-bit library can only be loaded by a 32-bit program.